# HTML5 / CSS: Is there a benefit in using multiple wrapper-divs within section-elements?

Tags: html, css

Years ago I have learned to made a website by putting everything below the body-tag into a div with a class "wrapper". 
These makes sense (without doubt) because that way one can align the whole content vertically and horizontally.

Yesterday I have seen this [video-tutorial](https://youtu.be/kXHoNdomHAs)

At 07:15 he tells that the technique I have described above shouldn't be used any longer. Instead one should use multiple section-tags and **within** that sections a div of class "wrapper".

So that the section-tags are full-screen and the content can be aligned with the wrapper-divs.

I've made this demo to tinker with such a structure:

```css
$color1: rgba(173, 216, 230, 1.0);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.content .wrap p {
  padding: 20px 5%;
}

.footer .wrap {
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="callout secondary">
      <h1>This is a Top-Headline.</h1>
      <p>This is a Sub-Header.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
    <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
      nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet
      adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
      tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="footer">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>&copy; 2017 by xyz</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I mean: It works. Of course ...

But I don't get the idea what's the concrete benefit. Currently I think it's just more HTML.

On the other hand I don't want to reject the idea without doing some inquiry.

Therefore:

**Can someone show me a concrete example of how one can benefit from having such a nested section-wrap structure? Respectively what purpose does it serve?**

Comment: Depends, but cleaner is better and more readable

Comment: Yep. That's the only reason which seemed to me reasonable too: It's more semantic. I just wonder if there might be benefit for layout etc. too when doing it that way ...

Comment: Based from the codes you provided, you can style with more control, unless the web site has very few design

Comment: Makes sense ... Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to talk about semantics, using section elements to mark up headers and footers is inappropriate. Use the header and footer elements instead. Using a section to mark up content separately from the header and footer is arguably inappropriate as well - the section should encompass the content *along with* the header and footer.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep. Valuable hint. Thanks.

Comment: +1 to `header` and `footer`. Also `main` instead of div.content (most probably) and `nav` for your main navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to put all content inside a `wrapper` or not to, all depends upon your requirement and how you want to manage it.

In Web2.0 websites we practiced `wrapper` div as parent and all content inside it - this gave a `fixed` width container and our content looks proper in the center of page.

But now since Web3.0, we focus more on responsive and full-screen websites and then sometimes it requires to have a specific or different `background-color` or `background-image` to one of the page sections, in such scenarios having multiple `wrapper` class structure comes to rescue. Check the code-snippet showing same approach. You can't get this same output in old approach with ease.

```css
section {
  padding: 30px 0;
  color: #333;
}

.section-1 {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}

.section-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-1024-720-6.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- I need a image as background and then text inside -->
<section class="bg">
  <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section-2">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome answered. :) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's CSS2 and CSS3. There is no CSS 3.0, and the versioning of CSS2 is insignificant to authors.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry bud, It was to be web2.0 and web3.0 - my mistake. will fix it :)